# Как поправить текст с использованием словаря в массиве не теряя форматирование текста?

Tags: php, строки

### Краткое описание

У меня есть обычное предложение который написано в неправильном форме. И мне нужно исправить предложение используя слова в моем словаре. Так ка с помощью функции `str_replace()` это не возможно в моем случае. Нужно использовать `similar_text()`. То что я сам делал я приведу внизу но он не возвращает то что мне нужно.

### Примеры

#### Входящая строка:

*Слова которые выделено жирными в строке, требует поправки:*

**Техподержка** 24/7 на **саом** деле **означет**, что **ночю** в саппорте **сидт** **психотерпевты**, под тем или иным соусом **уговавающие** потерпеть с решением **проблмы** до утра. **Изините**, сайт **stackverflow.cm** не работает в **свзи** с **перездом**.

#### Словарь:

```
$dictionary = array(
  'техподдержка',
  'означает',
  'на',
  'самом',
  'деле',
  'что',
  'ночью',
  'в',
  'саппорте',
  'сидят',
  'психотерапевты',
  'под',
  'тем',
  'или',
  'иным',
  'уговаривающие',
  'соусом',
  'потерпеть',
  'с',
  'решением',
  'проблемы',
  'до',
  'утра',
  'извините',
  'сайт',
  'stackoverflow',
  'com',
  'не',
  'работает',
  'связи',
  'с',
  'переездом',
);
```

#### Мой код:

```
$input = array("техподержка", "саом", "означет", "ночю");
foreach ($input as $in) {
$match = 0;
    foreach ($dictionary as $correct) {
similar_text($correct, $in, $percent);
    if ($percent > $match) {
        $result = $correct;
        $match = $percent;
    }
}
echo "$in поправлено на $result\r\n";
}
```

Но в моем коде я могу поправит слова только из массива используя свой словарь. Но мне нужно исправить текст а не значение из массива. И получить такой результат:

#### Нужный результат:

Техподдержка 24/7 на самом деле означает, что ночью в саппорте сидят психотерапевты, под тем или иным соусом уговаривающие потерпеть с решением проблемы до утра. Извините, сайт stackoverflow.com не работает в связи с переездом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы с помощью этого кода можете получить итоговый результат в каком бы форматирование он не был. Но есть один но. Слова должно быть написаны или в **нижним** регистре или в **вверхном** или начало вверном а после в нижним. Пример написание слов.

```
Добро ДОБРО добро
```

#### Функция:

```
function similar_correcting($text, $words)
{
$dictionary = array();
$input = preg_replace('/[^а-яa-z -]/iu', ' ', mb_strtolower($text));
$input = array_unique(explode(' ', $input));

foreach ($input as $in) 
{
    $match = 0;
    foreach ($words as $correct) 
    {
        similar_text($correct, $in, $percent);
        if ($percent > $match) 
        {
            $result = $correct;
            $match = $percent;
        }
    }
    $dictionary[$in] = $result;
}

$text = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($dictionary) {
$word = mb_strtolower($m[0]);
if (isset($dictionary[$word])) {
    $repl = $dictionary[$word];
    if ($word === $m[0]) return $repl;
    if (mb_strtoupper($word) === $m[0]) return mb_strtoupper($repl);
    if (mb_convert_case($word,  MB_CASE_TITLE) === $m[0]) return mb_convert_case($repl,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
    for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($word); $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $mixed[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1) === mb_substr($m[0], $i, 1) 
            ? mb_substr($repl, $i, 1)
            : mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($repl, $i, 1));
    }
    return implode("", $mixed);
}
return $m[0];
}, $text);

return $text;
}
```

#### Ваш словарь

```
$words = [
    'техподдержка',
    'означает',
    'на',
    'самом',
    'деле',
    'что',
    'ночью',
    'в',
    'саппорте',
    'сидят',
    'психотерапевты',
    'под',
    'тем',
    'или',
    'иным',
    'уговаривающие',
    'соусом',
    'потерпеть',
    'с',
    'решением',
    'проблемы',
    'до',
    'утра',
    'извините',
    'сайт',
    'stackoverflow',
    'com',
    'не',
    'работает',
    'связи',
    'с',
    'переездом'
  ];
```

Использование функции `similar_correcting()`:

```
$text = 'Техподержка 24/7 на саом деле означет, что ночю в саппорте сидт психотерпевты, под тем или иным соусом уговавающие потерпеть с решением проблмы до утра. Изините, сайт stackverflow.cm не работает в свзи с перездом.';

echo similar_correcting($text, $words);
```

#### Результат:

Техподдержка 24/7 на самом деле означает, что ночью в саппорте сидят психотерапевты, под тем или иным соусом уговаривающие потерпеть с решением проблемы до утра. Извините, сайт stackoverflow.com не работает в связи с переездом.

Comment: +1 за ответь @John. Ваш решение работает корректно!

Answer (score -1):

В вашем случае, если не нужно учитывать ошибки при слитых вместе словах, хватит разделения строки на части в массив и дальнейшей обработки отдельных слов. Пример реализации через `preg_split`: https://repl.it/NWvi/1

```
function correctMistakes(string $text, int $match = 0) : string {
  static $dictionary = [
    'техподдержка',
    'означает',
    'на',
    'самом',
    'деле',
    'что',
    'ночью',
    'в',
    'саппорте',
    'сидят',
    'психотерапевты',
    'под',
    'тем',
    'или',
    'иным',
    'уговаривающие',
    'соусом',
    'потерпеть',
    'с',
    'решением',
    'проблемы',
    'до',
    'утра',
    'извините',
    'сайт',
    'stackoverflow',
    'com',
    'не',
    'работает',
    'связи',
    'с',
    'переездом'
  ];

  $words = preg_split('/([\s\.]+)/', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  foreach($words as $i=>$word) {
    $min = $match;
    if($i % 2) continue;
    foreach($dictionary as $correct) {
      similar_text($correct, $word, $perc);
      if($perc > $min) {
        $words[$i] = $correct;
        $min = $perc;
      }
    }
  }
  $words[0] = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($words[0], 0, 1)) . mb_substr($words[0], 1);
  return join('', $words);

}

$text = 'Техподержка 24/7 на саом деле означет, что ночю в саппорте сидт психотерпевты, под тем или иным соусом уговавающие потерпеть с решением проблмы до утра. Изините, сайт stackverflow.cm не работает в свзи с перездом.';

echo correctMistakes($text);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответь. Но в Вашем примере теряется входной форматирование текста. Например символ `,` перед словом `под` и еще слова `Изините` заменен на `извините` который должен был заменен на .`Извините`. То есть есть проблема и по форматирование и по регистру слов в Вашем примере решение. @Screaming Voices

Comment: @Otabek я конечно всё понимаю, но мой пример на то и пример, что показывает путь, а не полную реализацию. Сверх алгоритмы и т.д. - это уже задача ваша или фрилансера. Но так и быть, обновил пример https://repl.it/NWvi/2

Comment: Ваша условия получение регистр в исходном виде некорректен. Вы ищите точку в входном тексте и букву после точки конвертируйте в верхний регистр так? @Screaming Voices.

Comment: Что если слова **извините** написано не после точки в вверхном регистре?